Enable Smarty Version 5
I'm running a Drupal 7 site with CiviCRM version 5.73.1
I understand that CiviCRM will be upgrading Smarty from version 2 to 5 soon (re: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4146) and I would like to test this ahead of time
Can anyone detail the step by step process for switching to Smarty version 5?
Many thanks :)

Put this line from the latest civicrm.settings.php template in civicrm.settings.php:
define('CIVICRM_SMARTY_AUTOLOAD_PATH', $civicrm_root . '/packages/smarty5/Smarty.php');
You said drupal 7 but note for drupal 10 it would be the other line below it because packages is in a different spot.
Note in 5.73 you will get some errors that are fixed in later versions.

Thank you for you help
